# Using Splice to Copy File to stdout

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

Is it possible to use the `splice` sys-call to copy a file to standard output? This seems like it would be trivial, yet I am having difficulty.  I have tried the following code and had no success:

```
void example(char *filename) {
    int buf_size = 2048;

    FILE* f = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (f == NULL){
        perror(filename);
        exit(1);
    }
    int fd = fileno(f);

    int filedes[2];
    if(pipe(filedes) < 0){
        perror("pipe");
        exit(1);
    }

    struct stat st;

    if (fstat(fd, &st) < 0){
        perror("fstat");
        exit(1);
    }

    off_t to_print = st.st_size;
    loff_t i_off = 0;
    loff_t o_off = 0;

    while(to_print > 0){
        if(buf_size > to_print) buf_size = to_print;

        ssize_t r = splice(fd,&i_off,filedes[1],NULL,buf_size, SPLICE_F_MORE | SPLICE_F_MOVE);

        if (r < 0){
            perror("splice");
            exit(1);
        }
        r = splice(filedes[0],NULL,STDOUT_FILENO,&o_off,buf_size, SPLICE_F_MORE | SPLICE_F_MOVE);

        if (r < 0){
            perror("splice2");
            exit(1);
        }

        to_print -= buf_size;
    }

    close(fd);
    close(filedes[0]);
    close(filedes[1]);
}
```

To be specific, the second splice fails with *Invalid argument*.  Any ideas where I am going wrong with this example?

Comment: Example is not compilable - where are your `#include` statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You provide an out offset in this call:

```
        r = splice(filedes[0],NULL,STDOUT_FILENO,&o_off,buf_size, SPLICE_F_MORE | SPLICE_F_MOVE);
```

... but the terminal isn't seekable. Change `&o_off` to `NULL`.

Comment: You are correct, an obvious error on my part.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The call to `splice()` returns EINVAL when stdout refers to a non-seekable stream. I tried your program and it fails when stdout refers to the terminal. However, it succeeds when stdout is redirected to a regular file.